# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when removed "Launch in browser" for new created ASP.NET Core app with docker

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, .net-core

I've created new ASP.NET Core WebApi (.NET 7) app with docker support and launched it - all good. But every time when I launch - new browser window opens. I've removed **Launch in browser** in **launchSettings** - now when I rebuild an app and run - I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.
Interesting notice - when I run an app with checked **Launch in browser**, stop it, remove **Launch in browser** and run again - it works (before next rebuild).

Is it possible to run an app without **Launch in browser** setting?